# How Do I Make Sure That Dispatch Notify is Called at the Right Time

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have scenario where I have to iterate over a list of account numbers, go and fetch the detail information for these accounts and then pass the aggregated information to completionBlock. In order to facilitate this I'm using dispatch_group_* methods. Unfortunately, the completion block is being called *before* the group has finished even though I have explicitly called

`dispatch_group_wait(_imfDispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);`

Example of console log (original):

> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.722 ThreadingHell[81909:303] inside loginResponse
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.724 ThreadingHell[81909:303] inside account loop
>   for obj: account1
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.724 ThreadingHell[81909:303] inside account loop
>   for obj: account2
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.724 ThreadingHell[81909:1b03] inside details:
>   L0i6kRVzGG details
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.724 ThreadingHell[81909:1a03] inside details:
>   SE0QjhO8Hh details
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.724 ThreadingHell[81909:303] inside account loop
>   for obj: account3
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.725 ThreadingHell[81909:1a03] inside completion
>   for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_015
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.725 ThreadingHell[81909:1803] inside details:
>   9SsGYOX3u5 details
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.725 ThreadingHell[81909:1a03] details are found
>   for account
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.725 ThreadingHell[81909:303] inside account loop
>   for obj: account4
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.725 ThreadingHell[81909:1b03] inside completion
>   for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_015
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.726 ThreadingHell[81909:1803] inside completion
>   for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_015
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.726 ThreadingHell[81909:303] inside account loop
>   for obj: acount5
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.726 ThreadingHell[81909:1a03] success account
>   looop
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.726 ThreadingHell[81909:1b03] details are found
>   for account
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.726 ThreadingHell[81909:2303] inside details:
>   wSXis5bIVs details
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.728 ThreadingHell[81909:1803] details are found
>   for account
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.728 ThreadingHell[81909:2403] inside details:
>   SrIfbzBLr7 details
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.728 ThreadingHell[81909:1a03] current instance of
>   accountDetails: (
>       "L0i6kRVzGG details" )
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.728 ThreadingHell[81909:1803] success account
>   looop
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.728 ThreadingHell[81909:1b03] success account
>   looop
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.729 ThreadingHell[81909:2403] inside completion
>   for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_015
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.729 ThreadingHell[81909:303] !!!!!!!!!! about to
>   call completion block. This should be last
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.729 ThreadingHell[81909:2303] inside completion
>   for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_015
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.730 ThreadingHell[81909:1803] current instance of
>   accountDetails: (
>       "L0i6kRVzGG details",
>       "9SsGYOX3u5 details" )
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.730 ThreadingHell[81909:1b03] current instance of
>   accountDetails: (
>       "L0i6kRVzGG details",
>       "9SsGYOX3u5 details",
>       "SE0QjhO8Hh details" )
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.731 ThreadingHell[81909:2403] details are found
>   for account
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.731 ThreadingHell[81909:2303] details are found
>   for account
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.732 ThreadingHell[81909:2403] success account
>   looop
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.731 ThreadingHell[81909:303] obj: { }
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.732 ThreadingHell[81909:2303] success account
>   looop
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.732 ThreadingHell[81909:303] error: (null)
>
> 2012-10-28 13:58:46.732 ThreadingHell[81909:2403] current instance of
>   accountDetails: (
>       "L0i6kRVzGG details",
>       "9SsGYOX3u5 details",
>       "SE0QjhO8Hh details",
>       "wSXis5bIVs details" )

// UPDATED LOG from latest commit [https://github.com/kwylez/ThreadingHell/tree/80cc29fab142b4dc1f386df747c5142b28e2dd84]

> 2012-10-28 16:32:38.984 ThreadingHell[83171:303] inside loginResponse
>   2012-10-28 16:32:38.987 ThreadingHell[83171:303] inside account loop
>   for obj: account1 2012-10-28 16:32:38.987 ThreadingHell[83171:303]
>   inside account loop for obj: account2 2012-10-28 16:32:38.987
>   ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] inside details: CP3ioYdvXp details
>   2012-10-28 16:32:38.987 ThreadingHell[83171:303] inside account loop
>   for obj: account3 2012-10-28 16:32:38.987 ThreadingHell[83171:1a03]
>   inside details: 6k635XoJOV details 2012-10-28 16:32:38.987
>   ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] inside completion for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_0
>   2012-10-28 16:32:38.988 ThreadingHell[83171:1a03] inside completion
>   for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_0
>   2012-10-28 16:32:38.988 ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] details are found
>   for account 2012-10-28 16:32:38.988 ThreadingHell[83171:303] inside
>   account loop for obj: account4 2012-10-28 16:32:38.988
>   ThreadingHell[83171:1803] inside details: 2TjGF1fdaZ details
>   2012-10-28 16:32:38.989 ThreadingHell[83171:1a03] details are found
>   for account 2012-10-28 16:32:38.990 ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] success
>   account looop 2012-10-28 16:32:38.991 ThreadingHell[83171:1b03]
>   current instance of accountDetails: (
>       "CP3ioYdvXp details" ) 2012-10-28 16:32:38.990 ThreadingHell[83171:303] inside account loop for obj: acount5
>   2012-10-28 16:32:38.990 ThreadingHell[83171:2303] inside details:
>   0YiuX9gHsu details 2012-10-28 16:32:38.990 ThreadingHell[83171:1a03]
>   success account looop 2012-10-28 16:32:38.990
>   ThreadingHell[83171:1803] inside completion for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_0
>   2012-10-28 16:32:38.992 ThreadingHell[83171:2303] inside completion
>   for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_0
>   2012-10-28 16:32:38.992 ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] inside details:
>   9RcyOfjRa5 details 2012-10-28 16:32:38.992 ThreadingHell[83171:1a03]
>   current instance of accountDetails: (
>       "CP3ioYdvXp details",
>       "6k635XoJOV details" ) 2012-10-28 16:32:38.992 ThreadingHell[83171:1803] details are found for account 2012-10-28
>   16:32:39.005 ThreadingHell[83171:1803] success account looop
>   2012-10-28 16:32:39.005 ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] inside completion
>   for __66-[ModelManager
>   getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_0
>   2012-10-28 16:32:39.005 ThreadingHell[83171:2303] details are found
>   for account 2012-10-28 16:32:39.006 ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] details
>   are found for account 2012-10-28 16:32:39.006
>   ThreadingHell[83171:2303] success account looop 2012-10-28
>   16:32:39.006 ThreadingHell[83171:1803] current instance of
>   accountDetails: (
>       "CP3ioYdvXp details",
>       "6k635XoJOV details",
>       "2TjGF1fdaZ details" ) 2012-10-28 16:32:39.007 ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] success account looop 2012-10-28
>   16:32:39.007 ThreadingHell[83171:2303] current instance of
>   accountDetails: (
>       "CP3ioYdvXp details",
>       "6k635XoJOV details",
>       "2TjGF1fdaZ details",
>       "0YiuX9gHsu details" ) 2012-10-28 16:32:39.008 ThreadingHell[83171:1b03] current instance of accountDetails: (
>       "CP3ioYdvXp details",
>       "6k635XoJOV details",
>       "2TjGF1fdaZ details",
>       "0YiuX9gHsu details",
>       "9RcyOfjRa5 details" ) 2012-10-28 16:32:39.008 ThreadingHell[83171:303] !!!!!!!!!! about to call completion block.
>   This should be last 2012-10-28 16:32:39.009 ThreadingHell[83171:303]
>   obj: { } 2012-10-28 16:32:39.009 ThreadingHell[83171:303] error:
>   (null)

What "order of operation" have I missed?

Here is link to example project on github (code was too much to put here):

https://github.com/kwylez/ThreadingHell

Comment: +1 for the project name.

Comment: I updated the project and have gotten a bit closer. All "blocks" are excuting in the correct order, but final array is empty when putting back on final completionBlock. 

I edited the original question with new log to compare

Answer (score 0):

*(I haven't downloaded your project yet, answering on my phone, apologies...)*

Use NSOperationQueue instead. Add each operation as a dependency of your completion operation.

It's a much cleaner, more cocoa-like API. You shouldn't have to change much, since you can use NSBlockOperation and pass in the same blocks you're currently using for GCD.

Comment: I will probably go that route, but I feel like I'm close to a solution with GCD and would like to see it through...possibly having an NSOperationQueue and GCD solution.

Answer (score 0):

The latest code [commit](https://github.com/kwylez/ThreadingHell/tree/36aedfdfcbf6fbd7e1446088fcfaf743110c4442)

fixes the issue for the last comment I made, THUS my question is answered...using dispatch_group methods.

In the `getAccountDetailsForAccountNumber:completionBlock` method I removed the call to `dispatch_group_notify` and moved the "completion" block login in the `dispatch_group_async` method.  This fixes the issue due to the fact that the completion block is now apart of the queue task and `getAccountListMetaInformation:` will have to "obey" the `dispatch_group_wait` command as opposed to before the notification would receive the concurrent notify afterwards.

Comment: Can you give a summary of the changes you made, as it is this question is kind of useless without the linked project, and we don't like external dependencies here!